# How do I properly compare performance of machine learning models, in the case of a multi-output classification problem?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, knn

**TL,DR**: I'm looking for a good way to compare the output of different scikit learn ML models on a multi-output classification problem: labelling social media messages according to the different disaster response categories they might fall into. I'm currently just using precision_recall_fscore_support on each label and then averaging the results, but I'm not convinced that this is a good solution.

**In detail:** As part of an exercise I'm doing for an online data science course, I'm looking at a dataset of social media messages that occurred during natural disasters. The goal of the exercise is to train a machine learning model to classify these messages according to the various emergency departments they relate to, such as: aid_related, medical_help, weather_related, floods, etc...

So for example the following message: *"UN reports Leogane 80-90 destroyed. Only Hospi..."* is classed in my training data as 'medical_products', 'aid_related' and 'request'.

I've started off using scikit-learn's KNeighborsClassifier, and MultiOutputClassifier. I'm also using gridsearch to compare parameters inside the model:

```
pipeline = pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', MultiOutputClassifier(KNeighborsClassifier()))
])

parameters = { 'clf__estimator__n_neighbors': [5, 7]}

cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters)

cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

When I finally (it takes forever just with two parameteres to compare) get the model output, I've written the following function to pull out a matrix with the average precision, recall and fscore for each column:

```
def classify_model_output(y_test, y_pred):
classification_scores = []

for i, column in enumerate(y_test.columns):   classification_scores.append(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_test[column], y_pred[:, i]))


df_classification = pd.DataFrame(classification_scores)
df_classification.columns = ['precision', 'recall', 'fscore', 'support']
df_classification.set_index(y_test.columns, inplace=True)

# below loop splits the precision, recall and f-score columns into two, one for negatives and one for positives (0 and 1)
for column in df_classification.columns:
    column_1 = df_classification[column].apply(lambda x: x[0]).rename(column+str(0), inplace=True)
    column_2 = df_classification[column].apply(lambda x: x[1]).rename(column+str(1), inplace=True)
    df_classification.drop([column], axis=1, inplace=True)
    df_classification = pd.concat([df_classification, column_1, column_2], axis=1)

# finally, take the average of the dataframe to get a classifier for the model                                                                    
df_classification_avg = df_classification.mean(axis=0)
                                                                      
return df_classification_avg
```

The df_classification table which looks like this (top 5 rows):

[image]

And here's what I get when I compare the average classification tables (produced by the previous method) for *knn with 5 neighbors* (avg_knn), *knn with 7 neighbors* (knn_avg_2), and *random forest* (rf) - yellow cells represent the max for that row:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to interpret this. One the face of it it looks like Random Forest (rf) performed best. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve this, or if using the average even makes sense here.

Does anyone have any advice on the best way to accurately and transparently compare my models, in the case of a multioutput problem like this one?

Edit: updated code block with easier to read function, and added comparison of three models

Answer (score 0):

If your training data is not biased towards any particular output label, then you can go for your accuracy score. i.e. corresponding all labels, there is balanced amount of training data.

However if your data is imbalanced i.e. training data is more towards one or two particular output label then go for precision and recall.

Now between precision and recall , the choice depends on your need . If you are not much considered about accuracy go for recall e.g. on airport there is minimum chance that any bomb would be recovered from luggage, but you check all bags. That is recall.

When you are more considered about how much correct predictions are done from a sample , go for precision.

Comment: Thanks! My main question is about how to compare models when I have multiple outputs to look at. So I have an accuracy score, a precision score and a recall score for each possible category, making it hard to get an idea of which model is best. Going to edit my question with more info on this.